Nginx Server Running on VM
I found this strange issue can someone explain why is it happening and how can i correct it? Like when i using my cellular network then using mobile phones hotspot to connect to my computer then i try and access a nginx server running on my azure vm then it is not accessing it however when i use my router and connect to it and then try and access the nginx server running on my azure vm i can access it. Why am i facing this issue.
I don't know what is going wrong in my cellar network but if there is some issue then neither the router nor the cellular network should be able to access the nginx server on the vm.

I think you should ask at superuser.com ?  (see: What topics can I ask about here?)

If you created the VM from the computer on your home router network, perhaps you whitelisted the public IP during creation.
Go to your VM in the Azure Portal -> Networking -> Select your Virtual NIC -> Network Security Group.
In here, you should have inbound rules. Check if there is one corresponding to the port of your nginx server.

I created my VM using the same networking that i am trying to connect it with. @Architect Jamie

@AdityaSharma so you created in on the cellular network? Your question says it works on your home router, but not cellular. You need to check the inbound rules for the Network Security Group (NSG) associated with the nginx VM
